# Twitter Bootstrap dropdown active class not removed if aria extended is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and I'm adding a class via jQuery toggle to the dropdown menu. If I click the cog(the dropdown) it toggles just fine. But if I click out of the cog the dropdown menu active class is not remove. I tried removing it if the attribute aria-extended is false but it doesn't seem to be working. Need some help. check out the jsfiddle

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.cog-wrapper').removeClass('active');

$('.dropdown').click(function (){
$('.cog-wrapper').toggleClass('active');        
});
if($("span[aria-extended="false"]")){
$('.cog-wrapper').removeClass('active');
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dtello2012/ns4wz58c/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a click handler for anything that isn't in your menu:

http://jsfiddle.net/p8exm91q/

Relevant portion:

```
$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('#dropdownMenu1').length) {
        $(".cog-wrapper").removeClass("active");
    }        
});
```

If your click isn't something inside the menu, $(event.target).closest("#dropdownMenu1") will return nothing.